# Rails Validations with oauth2 and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

i have a validation on the create and save methods for the user model in rails with devise, but i have no clue as to why   user instance is created even if promo code is nil and the errors that should be added are not being displayed in my view with google oauth2

does anyone know what the problem is?

This is my route:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { confirmations: 'users/confirmations', omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks', registrations: 'users/registrations' }
```

this is my user.rb method:

```
  def self.from_omniauth(auth, promo_code)
    user = find_by(email: auth.info.email)
    if user
      user.update(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid)
    else
      user = where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_initialize do |new_user|
        new_user.email = auth.info.email
        new_user.username = "#{auth.info.first_name[0]}#{auth.info.last_name.strip}"
        new_user.first_name = auth.info.first_name
        new_user.last_name = auth.info.last_name
        new_user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
        if promo_code != nil  ||  promo_code != ""
          new_user.promo_code = promo_code
        end
      end
    end
    user.save
    unless user.confirmed?
      user.confirm
    end
    user
  end
```

this is my omniauth_callbacks_controller

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def google_oauth2
    promo_code = cookies[:promo_code]
    @user= User.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'], promo_code)
    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication 
    else
      session['devise.google_data'] = request.env['omniauth.auth'] 
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url, alert: @user.errors.full_messages.join("\n")
    end
  end 
end
```

this is my registrations controller

```
  def new
    super
    @user = User.new
    if session['devise.google_data'] && @user.apply_omniauth(session['devise.google_data'])
      @user.valid?
    end
  end

  def create
    if session['devise.google_data'] && @user.apply_omniauth(session['devise.google_data'])
      super do |resource|
        resource.save(validate: true)
      end
    else
      super
    end
  end
```

and this is the validation

```
  validate :check_promo_code_limit, on: [:create, :save]

  def check_promo_code_limit
    promo_codes = {
      "MARKI99" => 1,
      "PIERRE" => 2,
      "BREEZE" => 100
    }
    if promo_code.nil?
      errors.add(:promo_code, :need_promo_code)
    elsif promo_codes[promo_code] == nil
      errors.add(:promo_code, :inexistant_promo_code)
    elsif User.where(promo_code: promo_code).count >= promo_codes[promo_code]
      errors.add(:promo_code, :custom_validation_error)
    end
  end
```

This is the record that is created with a promo_code that is nil

```
 #<User id: 118, email: "marcabisaleh@gmail.com", created_at: "2024-01-23 13:09:10.568103000 +0000", updated_at: "2024-01-23 13:09:10.580275000 +0000", first_name: "Marc", last_name: "Bou Saleh", username: "MBou Saleh", foot_amount: 25.0, timezone: nil, max_slippage: 50.0, club_name: nil, show_tutorial: nil, is_expert: nil, tutorial_home: false, trade_modal_tutorial: false, eligible: "To be eligible for this tournament, you are missin...", seen_video: false, is_private: true, is_admin: false, promo_code: nil, is_influencer: false, influencer_promo_code: nil, commission_value: nil, provider: "google_oauth2", uid: "103103713083988234843", seen_video_phone: false>
```

Comment: You've pasted the same `self.from_omniauth` function as your user.rb above, and you haven't explained what "not working" means.

Comment: Edit your question please.

Comment: Done. I am sorry. It is the first question I post and I am struggling.

Comment: So now, can you add to your question the proof of your conjecture? Eg. show your log that demonstrates that a new record is being created with a `nil` `promo_code`.

Comment: Also, for your own testing (and perhaps for your actual app), I would recommend changing from `save` to `save!` so you see an exception for any validation error.

Comment: Done. Do you have any  leads to solve this problem?

Comment: As I mentioned previously, need to see the actual logs. It's probably `user.confirm` that's saving without validating. You'd be able to confirm it wasn't `user.save` if you'd changed it to the bang call

Comment: I solved it. The solution is in the answer section. Thanks!

Comment: Well done. Hopefully you learnt a bit more about the sort of detail/info you need to include. All the best.

Comment: I did! Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way:

this is new my user.rb

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth, promo_code)
    user = find_by(email: auth.info.email)
    if user
      user.update(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid)
    else
      user = where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_initialize do |new_user|
        new_user.email = auth.info.email
        new_user.username = "#{auth.info.first_name[0]}#{auth.info.last_name.strip}"
        new_user.first_name = auth.info.first_name
        new_user.last_name = auth.info.last_name
        new_user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
        if promo_code != nil  &&  promo_code != ""
          new_user.promo_code = promo_code
        end
      end
    end

    if user.valid?
      user.save!
      unless user.confirmed?
        user.confirm
      end
      user
    else
      user.errors.full_messages.join("\n")
      return user
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**